# Creation of pseudo device-node under /dev

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

#### Question:

- How to (where to find additional information i.e., examples) programatically create a **pseudo device-node** under **/dev** from a **kernel module**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I'm guessing your talking about Linux (since you are talking about kernel modules). In that case I'd strongly recommend reading [Linux Device Driver](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). I'd recommend looking at [chapter 14](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch14.pdf) to understand better how device work.

It should also be noted that in most current desktop and server distribution of Linux, [udev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev.html) is responsible for creating entries in /dev. You can configure udev with [rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) that allow you to create your the device node with a specific name and location. In the embedded world it might be mdev with busybox that's responsible for populating /dev or even it could simply be the deprecated devfs.

Answer (score 1):

[Linux Device Driver](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) is certainly a must read. However, I would start with chapter 3, since it is a step by step example on how to create a char device driver.

The kernel API is a moving target. More than often, you will discover that some example that used to compile against a previous version of the kernel generates a warning or an error with a newer version. In this situation, being able to [browse through the sources](http://lxr.linux.no/linux) without getting lost is very useful.